# adding bills after payment to user profile - hikashop

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, module, module-display, hikashop

I'm using hikashop for selling products in my website. I want to add user's bill to his profile after he completes the payment, so that he can have a summary of all his payment in his profile.
How can that be done? Is there any way to add the bills as module to user-profile? Do i have to write a separate component?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "bill", are you talking about the receipt for payment? So, you want to display an order history somewhere that the user can find?

Comment: @MichaelYaeger that's exactly correct. Can you plz help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is setup a "Customer Orders" page in your menu. Navigate to one of your menus and add a new item called "Customer orders" as shown below:

[image: HikaShop Menu Items]

If you want a list of different pages the customer has access to, you could create your own menu with those items and then add a "Menu" module to the sidebar of any/all pages to access them.

**To go a step further**, you could just create one of HikaShop's built-in "User control panel" menu items and all the customer info, including orders, will be listed on that page. You can see what that page looks like here:

[image: HikaShop User Control Panel]

To remove the advertisement, make sure you purchase one of the "premium" versions:
http://www.hikashop.com/extensions/compare-versions.html

Comment: You are welcome!